# How to increase the volume of iOS app playing generated PCM audio?

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, volume, pcm

I have a lot of experience writing embedded software on a variety of platforms and in a variety of languages, but this is my first iOS app.

This app emits audio data.  The data is different each time, and must be generated by the app on-the-fly.  It is encoded as 500Hz modulated PCM on a 12kHz carrier, lasting less than 100mS.  The volume of the data must be independent of the system volume.

All is working well, except that the volume of the data through the speaker is very low on most iPhones.  Through the receiver it is even worse, to the point of being unusable.  The volume on an iPad seems better.

Sadly, I don't have many physical iPhones to try this out on.

I chose to use the AudioUnits API because it is most compatible with PCM data.  An array of Float32 is populated with data sampled at 32kHz.  The 12kHz carrier data varies from +1.0 to -1.0 at full volume, and is scaled down for lower volumes if the user desires.

Here are some code snippets to examine.  There's nothing very exotic here, but maybe someone can point out what I am doing wrong.  I am omitting much of the structure and the iOS app-specific code, since I'm not having problems there.  Note also that there is more error-checking done than I have shown here, in the interest of brevity:

```
typedef Float32 SampleType;
AURenderCallbackStruct        renderCallbackStruct;
AVAudioSession              * session;
AudioComponentInstance        audioUnit;
AudioComponentDescription     audioComponentDescription;
AudioStreamBasicDescription   audioStreamBasicDesc;
UISlider IBOutlet           * volumeViewSlider;

static SampleType           * generatedAudioData; // Array to hold
                                                  // generated audio data  

...

// Description to use to find the default playback output unit:
audioComponentDescription.componentType         = kAudioUnitType_Output;
audioComponentDescription.componentSubType      = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO;
audioComponentDescription.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
audioComponentDescription.componentFlags        = 0; // Docs say: "Set this value to zero."
audioComponentDescription.componentFlagsMask    = 0; // Docs say: "Set this value to zero."

// Callback structure to use for setting up the audio unit:
renderCallbackStruct.inputProc       = RenderCallback;
renderCallbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = (__bridge void *)( self );

// Set the format for the audio stream in the AudioStreamBasicDescription (ASBD):
audioStreamBasicDesc.mBitsPerChannel   = BITS_PER_BYTE * BYTES_PER_SAMPLE; // (8 * sizeof ( SampleType ))
audioStreamBasicDesc.mBytesPerFrame    = BYTES_PER_SAMPLE;     
audioStreamBasicDesc.mBytesPerPacket   = BYTES_PER_SAMPLE;
audioStreamBasicDesc.mChannelsPerFrame = MONO_CHANNELS;            // 1
audioStreamBasicDesc.mFormatFlags      = (kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat | 
                                          kAudioFormatFlagsNativeEndian |
                                          kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked |
                                          kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved);
audioStreamBasicDesc.mFormatID         = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
audioStreamBasicDesc.mFramesPerPacket  = 1;  
audioStreamBasicDesc.mReserved         = 0;  
audioStreamBasicDesc.mSampleRate       = 32000;

session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setActive: YES error: &sessionError];
// This figures out which UISlider subview in the MPVolumeViews controls the master volume.
// Later, this is manipulated to set the volume to max temporarily so that the AudioUnit can
// play the data at the user's desired volume.
MPVolumeView * volumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] init];
for ( UIView *view in [volumeView subviews] )
{
  if ([view.class.description isEqualToString:@"MPVolumeSlider"])
  {
    volumeViewSlider = ( UISlider * ) view;
    break;
  }
}

...

// (This is freed later:)
generatedAudioData = (SampleType *) malloc ( lengthOfAudioData * sizeof ( SampleType ));

[session setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
         withOptions: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDuckOthers |  
                      AudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker
               error: &sessionError];
// Set the master volume to max temporarily so that the AudioUnit can
// play the data at the user's desired volume:
oldVolume = volumeViewSlider.value;  // (This is set back after the data is played)
[volumeViewSlider setValue: 1.0f animated: NO];

AudioComponent defaultOutput = AudioComponentFindNext ( NULL, &audioComponentDescription );

// Create a new unit based on this to use for output
AudioComponentInstanceNew ( defaultOutput, &audioUnit );

UInt32 enableOutput = 1;
AudioUnitElement outputBus = 0;
// Enable IO for playback
AudioUnitSetProperty ( audioUnit,
                       kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO,
                       kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                       outputBus,
                       &enableOutput,
                       sizeof ( enableOutput ) );

// Set the audio data stream formats:
AudioUnitSetProperty ( audioUnit,
                       kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
                       kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                       outputBus,
                       &audioStreamBasicDesc,
                       sizeof ( AudioStreamBasicDescription ) );

// Set the function to be called each time more input data is needed by the unit:
AudioUnitSetProperty ( audioUnit, 
                       kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback, 
                       kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                       outputBus, 
                       &renderCallbackStruct, 
                       sizeof ( renderCallbackStruct ) );

// Because the iPhone plays audio through the receiver by default,
// it is necessary to override the output if the user prefers to 
// play through the speaker:
// (if-then code removed for brevity)
[session overrideOutputAudioPort: AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker
                           error: &overrideError];
// The pcmEncoder fills generatedAudioData with the ... uh, well,
// the generated audio data:
[pcmEncoder createAudioData: generatedAudioData
              audioDataSize: lengthOfAudioData];  
AudioUnitInitialize ( audioUnit );
AudioOutputUnitStart ( audioUnit );

...

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
OSStatus RenderCallback ( void                       * inRefCon, 
                          AudioUnitRenderActionFlags * ioActionFlags, 
                    const AudioTimeStamp             * inTimeStamp, 
                          UInt32                       inBusNumber, 
                          UInt32                       inNumberFrames, 
                          AudioBufferList            * ioData)
{    
  SampleType * ioDataBuffer = (SampleType *)ioData->mBuffers[0].mData;

  // Check that the data has been exhausted, and if so, tear down the audio unit:
  if ( dataLeftToCopy <= 0 )
  { // Tear down the audio unit on the main thread instead of this thread:
    [audioController performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector ( tearDownAudioUnit )
                                      withObject: nil
                                   waitUntilDone: NO];
    return noErr;
  }
  // Otherwise, copy the PCM data from generatedAudioData to ioDataBuffer and update the index
  // of source data.

  ...  (Boring code that copies data omitted)

  return noErr;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
- (void) tearDownAudioUnit
{
  if ( audioUnit )
  {
    AudioOutputUnitStop ( audioUnit );
    AudioUnitUninitialize ( audioUnit );
    AudioComponentInstanceDispose ( audioUnit );
    audioUnit = nil;
  }
  // Change the session override back to play through the default output stream:
  NSError * deactivationError = nil;
  int errorInt = [session overrideOutputAudioPort: AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone
                                            error: &deactivationError];
  // Free the audio data memory:
  if ( generatedAudioData ) { free ( generatedAudioData ); generatedAudioData = nil; }
  [volumeViewSlider setValue: oldVolume animated: NO];
}
```

Manipulating the volume slider only seems to be necessary on the iPad, but it doesn't hurt on the iPhone, as far as I can tell.
Using different data types (SInt32, int16_t) for SampleType doesn't seem to make a difference.
Scaling the data greater than the range +1.0 to -1.0 only seems to result in clipping.

Would using a different API such as AudioServicesPlaySystemSound or AVAudioPlayer result in louder output?  They each present challenges, and I'm loath to implement them without some indication that it would help.
(My understanding is that I'd have to create a .caf container 'file' each time data is generated so that I can pass a URL to these APIs, then delete it after it is played.  I haven't seen an example of this particular scenario; maybe there's an easier way?  ... but that's a different question.)

Is the typical iPhone's speaker and receiver just not capable of pumping 12kHz out at a usable volume?  I find that hard to believe.

Thanks in advance for any help!

**Update: 1/13/2015**
Finally acquired an iPhone 5C to work with. Here is the response of the speaker when playing several different frequencies.  These measurements were made in a soundproof environment with high-end recording equipment:

[image: 1-2-4-8-10-12kHz]

Note how much rolloff is exhibited from 1kHz to 12kHz, and that the output is even worse at 10kHz than at 12kHz.  Furthermore, the output appears to be post-processed somehow:

[image: 1kHz_Post_Processing]

I also implemented and compared three different APIs: AudioUnits, AudioServicesPlaySystemSound and AVAudioPlayer.  The differences between them were not significant.

I **was** able to remove the post-processing by setting the AVAudioSession mode to AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement instead of AVAudioSessionModeDefault, but still no joy on increasing the volume.  I'm thinking that the iPhones just aren't capable of outputting 12kHz at usable volume.

Comment: 12kHz is really high! The highest note on a piano is under 2kHz, yes? Is this even audible on a phone line? It's also within the top octave of human audibility.

Comment: You are correct.  The audio data is not meant to be heard, it is being transmitted to other devices which can decode it.  This is a legacy frequency which is, unfortunately, not negotiable.

Comment: If you are already reaching the clipping point, it seems to me the only hope for making the sound louder would be to attach an external speaker, one known to support sounds at the desired Hz. Or maybe make use of a headphone out line. Either that or lower the carrier to audible frequencies. I assume it would be common for speakers on a little hand-held device to reflect cost cuts by not supporting frequencies that high.

Comment: I have considered the same conclusions, but I am hoping that I have just missed some way of playing out the audio data more loudly, due to my lack of knowledge of the iOS APIs.  
It is certainly true that tiny speakers have a limited frequency response, but I would think that they should do better at higher frequencies than lower.